# unit testing admin password

Tags: unit-tests

I'm writing up unit tests for my plugin and I need a logged in user to test, but I can't find the admin password anywhere. Does anybody know what the default admin password is? I'm extending the `WP_UnitTestCase` and taking the tests from https://unit-tests.svn.wordpress.org/trunk.

My code at the moment:

```
<?php
require_once('myPlugin.php');

class MyPluginTest extends WP_UnitTestCase{

    function setUp(){
        wp_signon(array(
            'user_login' => 'admin',
            'user_password' => 'no_idea'
        ));
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The password is … `password`. You can see that in [`includes/install.php`](https://github.com/kurtpayne/wordpress-unit-tests/blob/master/includes/install.php):

```
wp_install( WP_TESTS_TITLE, 'admin', WP_TESTS_EMAIL, true, null, 'password' );
```

The last parameter is the admin password.

Comment: I feel like a pleb, almost so much as to remove the question out of embarrassment ;) cheers.

Comment: @Coombesy It is not that bad. The password should be mentioned in the readme file. Now, when someone else searches for it, it can be found with a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=WordPress+unit+test+admin+password).